# API call for Openshift (e.g. 4.14) to get token using Postman

Tags: oauth, postman, openshift

I am trying to get via API call token for using it in Openshift so I can be authenticated/authorized and execute more API calls

a) As URL I used "https://oauth-openshift.apps.domain/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=openshift-browser-client

b) I used basic authentication user/password

c) the only header I used is X-CSRF-Token: xxx

I get response 200, but the token is not shown. It just says "Display Token", but cannot see it

I tried to change the response_type=token, client_id=openshift-challenging-client, but it doesn't work.

How can I get the token in postman to save it and use it in the next API calls (e.g. get pods, projects etc)?

When I use curl (response_type=token, client_id=openshift-challenging-client) from my jump server I get the token, but my target is to do that in postman

*curl example that worked*
curl -v --insecure --user user:password --header "X-CSRF-Token: xxx" --url "https://oauth-openshift.apps.domain/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=openshift-challenging-client" 2>&1 | grep -oP "access_token=\K[^&]*"

From Postman:

[image]

Using resonse=token, client_id=openshift-challenging-client, the return is this. I get 200 with the below message, but test fails
[image]
[image]

The "display token" comes when I use response=code, client_id=openshift-browser-client. No error with the test, but I don't get the token again

[image]

Comment: Can you show curl's full command and response with hide credential? And screen capture of your Postman try with header, body information. It will help to answer your question.

Comment: Just updated it. Could it be the -v --insecure that makes the difference? I don't know if this can be added in postman calls

Comment: It helped with your updated item, I answered it, and I hope to address your question.

Comment: @BenchVue first of all, thank you so much for the effort! a) When I use response_type=token, client_id=openshift-challenging-client, I get a body return as above and test fails (since return is not as accepted). b) When I use response_type=code, client_id=openshift-browser-client, I still see Display Token and not the token. I have added the new pictures in the original post

Comment: The reason is your HTML string and mine are not same. I updated end of my answer, can you try it, still error, just update your question with your body of response for HTML string after replace your token with dummy string. I can try to find regular expression.

Comment: The problem is that it returns "Display Token"  there and not the token. The regex is correct if there was a token like in your case, unfortunately in my case I just receive a text "Display Token" as shown in my screenshot

Comment: OK, the token will store cookies in side of Browser, do you know API documentation

Answer (score 0):

##### Handling access token in Postman

Postman sets the value of the `access_token` variable in the Postman environment to the value stored in the Access Token variable.

```js
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", accessToken);
```

[image]

This sets the access_token as a Bearer Token, allowing it to be accessed using the placeholder {{access_token}}. This token can then be dynamically used in subsequent requests for authentication purposes.

[image]

##### Parsing `Access Token` in Postman

`Input : HTML`

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="abc123token">
    <button type="submit">
      ee7fdbd598bf649359115e05b9a4e476a85ec6d9bc3c99af39476e66bb1db25c
      </button>
</form>
```

Parsing

```
var accessToken = htmlResponse.match(/<button type="submit">([^<]+)<\/button>/)[1].trim();
```

Setting/Getting via 'EnvironmentVariable'

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", accessToken);
console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("access_token"));
```

log will display bottom/left side in Postmam
[image]

##### Mocking your  Openshift server

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const crypto = require('crypto');

let accessToken; // Variable to store the access token

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS

// Get Token Endpoint
app.get('/oauth/authorize', (req, res) => {

    // Check if Authorization header is present
    if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        res.status(401).send('<h1>Unauthorized</h1>');
        return;
    }

    // Extract the base64 encoded credentials
    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    // Decode the base64 encoded credentials
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');

    // Extract username and password from credentials
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');

    // Check if username and password are valid
    if (username !== 'abcd' || password !== '1234') {
        res.status(401).send('<h1>Unauthorized</h1>');
        return;
    }

    const responseType = req.query.response_type;
    const csrfToken = req.headers['x-csrf-token'];
    const clientId = extractClientId(csrfToken);

    // Hash the CSRF token
    accessToken = hashToken(csrfToken);

    // Construct HTML response
    const htmlResponse = `
    <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="${csrfToken}">
      <button type="submit">
      ${accessToken}
      </button>
    </form>
  `;

    res.send(htmlResponse);
});

// Update data API End point 
app.put('/data', (req, res) => {
    const bearerToken = req.headers.authorization;

    // Check if Authorization header is present and contains Bearer token
    if (!bearerToken || bearerToken.indexOf('Bearer ') === -1) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized: Bearer token missing' });
        return;
    }

    const accessTokenFromHeader = bearerToken.split('Bearer ')[1]; // Extract the Bearer token

    // Check if the access token matches the expected value
    if (accessTokenFromHeader !== accessToken) {
        res.status(403).json({ error: 'Forbidden: Invalid access token' });
        return;
    }

    const updatedData = { message: "Data updated successfully" };
    res.json(updatedData); // Send the updated data in JSON format
});

// Function to extract client ID from CSRF token
function extractClientId(csrfToken) {
    // For simplicity, let's assume the CSRF token contains the client ID at the end of the token.
    return csrfToken.slice(-20); // Extract last 20 characters as client ID
}

function hashToken(token) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(token).digest('hex');
}

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

##### Install server dependencies

```
npm install express cors crypto
```

##### Run it

```
node server.js
```

[image]

##### cURL testing

User ID : user
User Password: 1234

```
curl \
--silent \
--insecure \
--user abcd:1234 \
--header "X-CSRF-Token: abc123token" \
--url "http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=openshift-challenging-client"
```

The output will response HTML format as similar your response

[image]

##### Testing by Postman

##### #1 Get Token

```
GET http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=openshift-challenging-client
```

[image]

Basic Auth
[image]

`Header`
[image]

`Tests`

```
var htmlResponse = pm.response.text();
var accessToken = htmlResponse.match(/<button type="submit">([^<]+)<\/button>/)[1].trim();

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", accessToken);
console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("access_token"));
```

[image]

Result
[image]

##### #2 Update Data call with access token

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/data
```

Select Type with `Bearer Token` and Enter <kbd>{{access_token}}</kbd>

[image]

It will use some names of Environment variables (my demo is 'dev')
In Postman UI, right/top side.

[image]

##### Result of PUT call using access token

`Pre-request Script` just logging
[image]

[image]

---

##### Update

Replace in `Tests` tab

```js
var htmlResponse = pm.response.text();

var matchResult = htmlResponse.match(/<button type="submit">\s*([^<\s]+)\s*<\/button>/);

// Check if the match result is not null
if (matchResult && matchResult.length > 1) {
    var accessToken = matchResult[1].trim();
    // Set the access token value as a global variable
    postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", accessToken);
} else {
    console.log("Access token not found in the HTML response");
}

console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("access_token"));
```

If still not finding access token.

You need to find the correct regular expression string

Go this site

```
https://regex101.com/
```

##### Step 1

Put **REGULAR EXPRESSION**

```
<button type="submit">\s*([^<\s]+)\s*<\/button>
```

Put **TEST STRING**

```html
</style>


<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="sha256~PcJ_i3E0t84RmewmfRLC5Y0mW29Das2bte5__9sfZ6c">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="LSt2kbfFXKtyg2M0CHeYTcvlH94_Am0m_wutZc5p6bs">
    <button type="submit">
        ee7fdbd598bf649359115e05b9a4e476a85ec6d9bc3c99af39476e66bb1db25c
    </button>
</form>
```

**Result**

[image]

`Right Side`

[image]

`Both display`
[image]

##### Step 2

Put **REGULAR EXPRESSION**
As same as Step 1

Put **TEST STRING**
From your Postman's  Body Output
[image]

If matches your token finding, use that regular expression

If still failed, copy your Body and update your question after TOKEN STRING - replace dummy string.