# insomnia how to extract the value from an input html response

Tags: insomnia

I have the following HTML and I want to extract the value from the input with a name equal to code, using insomnia.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Return</title>
        <script>
window.onload=function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("redirect_form");
    form.submit();
}
        </script>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/ 
document.cookie = "IV_JCT=%2Foauth; path=/;secure";
/*]]>*/ 
</SCRIPT>
</head>
    <body>
      <p>Return....</p>
      <form id="redirect_form" name="redirect_form" action="https://example.com/login/callbackmfe" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="code" value="yDCKqoCgXDAEdeY2d01ln43gaHerP2" />
      <input type="hidden" name="iss" value="https://example.com" />
      <input type="hidden" name="state" value="testing" />
      
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've already tried several ways:
`/html/body/input[@name='code']/@value` OR `(//input[@name='code'])[1]/@value`

What would you be doing wrong?

Insomnia  Version

> Version: Insomnia 2023.2.2
> V8: 10.8.168.20-electron.0

[See the imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgW6O.png)

Comment: I don't know how to run a script in `insomnia` but I know to handle a HTML parsing in `postman` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78127721/api-call-for-openshift-e-g-4-14-to-get-token-using-postman/78130150#78130150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Insomnia defect. the `<html>` tag need `<!DOCTYPE>` Declaration.
If have no `!DOCTYPE` can't parse.

Your HTML tag missing `!DOCTYPE`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Insomnia recognized HTML tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

##### demo server

Save as `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// //input[@type='hidden' and @name='code']/@value
app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    const htmlContent = `
    <!DOCTYPE html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Return</title>
            <script>
    window.onload=function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("redirect_form");
        form.submit();
    }
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.cookie = "IV_JCT=%2Foauth; path=/;secure";
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Return....</p>
            <form id="redirect_form" name="redirect_form" action="https://example.com/login/callbackmfe" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="code" value="yDCKqoCgXDAEdeY2d01ln43gaHerP2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="iss" value="https://example.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="state" value="testing" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    `;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(htmlContent);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express
```

##### Run Server

```
node server.js
```

##### Call by Insomnia

[image]

##### Parsing HTML by Insomnia

[image]

Detail steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142188/http-request-to-keycloak-with-insommia/78144420#78144420)

<kbd>XPath</kbd>

```
//input[@type='hidden' and @name='code']/@value
```

[image]

I am using this version. I hope to fix in the next version.

[image]

##### Note

Postman can do by this `Tests` script

```
var htmlResponse = pm.response.text();

var codeValue = htmlResponse.match(/<input type="hidden" name="code" value="([^"]+)" \/>/);
```

Comment: In fact, there is an `<!DOCTYPE>´, but it is in another format. See below: ```<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>```

As it is a server where I cannot change the return format, it will not work here for me.
Is there any script that can handle the html return?

But your solution works. I was here using node and it worked. I'll mark your solution as correct, as the problem here is another out of control one.

Comment: Thanks for your accept and happy to hear got a solution by node.js